# How to make component to re render after changing State and pressing button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, rendering

I'm new to react and I'm developing a component that uses a DatePicker and with the date selected it renders Pages that contain some charts.

My problem here is that every time I change the startDate variable by selecting a new date in the DatePicker. And the desired behavior I'd like to have here is to:

1. Select the date from the Date Picker
2. Press button "Update dashboard"
3. Re render all components

I.e, wait for the button to be pressed to re render all components.

Can someone explain to me how can I manage to implement this behavior?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
 
// CSS Modules, react-datepicker-cssmodules.css// 
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css';
import Spinner from '../../components/layout/Spinner';



//Cards Paginas
import Pagina1 from '../../components/tableros/Cards/Pagina1';
import Pagina2 from '../../components/tableros/Cards/Pagina2';
import Pagina3 from '../../components/tableros/Cards/Pagina3';
import Pagina4 from '../../components/tableros/Cards/Pagina4';
import Pagina5 from '../../components/tableros/Cards/Pagina5';
import Pagina6 from '../../components/tableros/Cards/Pagina6';

const ReporteDiario = () => {

  
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [renderPages, setRenderPages] = useState(true);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setRenderPages(!renderPages);
  }

  // Para poder actualizar los componentes cada que se cambie la fecha
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [renderPages]);

  function PagesComponent() {
    return (
      <div className="cards-container">
        <Pagina1 
          date={startDate} />
        <Pagina2  />
        <Pagina3  />
        <Pagina4  />
        <Pagina5 />
        <Pagina6 />
      </div>
    );
  }
  return (
    <>
    <aside className='col-span-2 border-2 border-blue-600'>
        <div className="form-group">  
        <DatePicker
          selected={startDate}
          showIcon
          onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
          isClearable
          dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
          placeholderText="Select date"
          closeOnScroll={true}
        />
        </div>  
    </aside>

    

    <div>
    <button id='ReporteDiario' onClick={handleClick} className='text-left pl-1 my-1 border-2 border-blue-600'>
       Update Dashboard
    </button>
    {renderPages && <PagesComponent/>}
    </div>

    </>
  )
}

export default ReporteDiario
```

I've been looking how to use hooks like **useEffect, useRef**, but at the moment I haven't been able to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

David you can use [Refs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useRef) in react. you can do it update the ref and on button press update the state from the ref.

Hope this helps :)

You do instead of changing the state directly. Have a func that store's the value in a ref
Ex:

```
const myRef = useRef(new Date());
```

And changes on datepicker component

```
<DatePicker
    selected={startDate}
    showIcon
    onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
    isClearable
    dateFormat="yyyy-MM-dd"
    placeholderText="Select date"
    closeOnScroll={true}
/>
```

change the handleClick using the value from ref

```
const handleClick = () => {
  // setRenderPages(!renderPages);
  setStartDate(myRef.current)
}
```

Bdw, Here is a working [demo](https://playcode.io/1440737).

Comment: Do you think you can explain me what do I need to change and how to use useRef in my particular, I'm bit lost, I've been trying to useRef for the startDate, but still after changing the date in the datepicker it still re render automatically all my Pagina components

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer and made a demo too. It should work like you want now.

Comment: I forgot to thank you, thanks a lot! Just one last question, is there a way that when I select I new date it changes in the calendar when I select it? This is to make it more use friendly

Comment: Hey, I've updated the demo. Looks like is the date pickers problem it needs setState to re-render the DatePicker component.